# Eclipse is compiling with with libopencm3 for STM32F0 but not for STM32F1

Tags: c++, eclipse, arm, stm32, libopencm3

I managed it to get a working blink template with libopencm3 for the STM32F051 (@ stmf0discovory). Then I wanted to get a working one for my Maple Mini (with STM32F103 = cortex-m3) so I copied the first one and changed the cpu flag from cortex-m0-plus to cortex-m3, the library from opencm3_stm32f0 to opencm3_stm32f1 and so on...

But as you can guess its not compiling. From the compilation log it seems like the compiler is not invoking the linker and thats why its not finding the `gpio_mode_setup` function and definistions like `GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT`. Here are the Eclipse console outputs:

**str32f0 - working:**

```
19:07:01 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Template ****
make all 
'Building file: ../Source/main.c'
'Invoking: Cross ARM C Compiler'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -mlittle-endian -Og -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -msoft-float -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow  -g3 -ggdb -DSTM32F0 -I"C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include" -I"C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template/Include" -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls -Wa,-adhlns="Source/main.o.lst" -v -MMD -MP -MF"Source/main.d" -MT"Source/main.o" -c -o "Source/main.o" "../Source/main.c"
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/src/gcc/configure --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw --libexecdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/lib --infodir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info --mandir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/man --htmldir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/html --pdfdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/pdf --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-headers=yes --with-newlib --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-sysroot=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/arm-none-eabi --with-libiconv-prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-gmp=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-mpfr=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-mpc=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-isl=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-cloog=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-libelf=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors' --with-multilib-list=armv6-m,armv7-m,armv7e-m,cortex-m7,armv7-r
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288] (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mcpu=cortex-m0plus' '-mthumb' '-mlittle-endian' '-Og' '-fmessage-length=0' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fno-common' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wmissing-declarations' '-Wshadow' '-g3' '-ggdb' '-D' 'STM32F0' '-I' 'C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include' '-I' 'C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template/Include' '-std=gnu11' '-Wmissing-prototypes' '-Wstrict-prototypes' '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' '-Wredundant-decls' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MF' 'Source/main.d' '-MT' 'Source/main.o' '-c' '-o' 'Source/main.o'
 c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -I C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include -I C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template/Include -imultilib armv6-m -iprefix c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/ -isysroot c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../arm-none-eabi -MMD Source/main.d -MF Source/main.d -MP -MT Source/main.o -dD -D__USES_INITFINI__ -D STM32F0 ../Source/main.c -quiet -dumpbase main.c -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -auxbase-strip Source/main.o -g3 -ggdb -Og -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls -std=gnu11 -version -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -o C:\Users\Lenny\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN3qnLh.s
GNU C (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) version 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288] (arm-none-eabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.4, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../arm-none-eabi/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../arm-none-eabi/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include
 C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template/Include
 c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include
 c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include-fixed
 c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include
End of search list.
GNU C (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) version 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288] (arm-none-eabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.4, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 9d74dec9c13b63cc54577fa808c91d66
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mcpu=cortex-m0plus' '-mthumb' '-mlittle-endian' '-Og' '-fmessage-length=0' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fno-common' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wmissing-declarations' '-Wshadow' '-g3' '-ggdb' '-D' 'STM32F0' '-I' 'C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include' '-I' 'C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template/Include' '-std=gnu11' '-Wmissing-prototypes' '-Wstrict-prototypes' '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' '-Wredundant-decls' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MF' 'Source/main.d' '-MT' 'Source/main.o' '-c' '-o' 'Source/main.o'
 c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/as.exe -v -I C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include -I C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template/Include -EL -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mfloat-abi=soft -meabi=5 -adhlns=Source/main.o.lst -o Source/main.o C:\Users\Lenny\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN3qnLh.s
GNU assembler version 2.24.0 (arm-none-eabi) using BFD version (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.24.0.20150604
COMPILER_PATH=c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/armv6-m/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mcpu=cortex-m0plus' '-mthumb' '-mlittle-endian' '-Og' '-fmessage-length=0' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fno-common' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wmissing-declarations' '-Wshadow' '-g3' '-ggdb' '-D' 'STM32F0' '-I' 'C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include' '-I' 'C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template/Include' '-std=gnu11' '-Wmissing-prototypes' '-Wstrict-prototypes' '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' '-Wredundant-decls' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MF' 'Source/main.d' '-MT' 'Source/main.o' '-c' '-o' 'Source/main.o'
'Finished building: ../Source/main.c'
' '
'Building target: Template.elf'
'Invoking: Cross ARM C Linker'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -mlittle-endian -Og -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -msoft-float -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow  -g3 -ggdb -T "C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template\Misc\stm32f0-discovery.ld" -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections -L"C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\lib" -Wl,-Map,"Template.map" -Xlinker --cref --specs=nano.specs -v --static -Wl,--start-group -lc -lgcc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group -o "Template.elf"  ./Source/main.o   -lopencm3_stm32f0 -lc_nano -lnosys
Using built-in specs.
Reading specs from c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/nano.specs
rename spec link to nano_link
rename spec link_gcc_c_sequence to nano_link_gcc_c_sequence
COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/src/gcc/configure --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw --libexecdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/lib --infodir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info --mandir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/man --htmldir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/html --pdfdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/pdf --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-headers=yes --with-newlib --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-sysroot=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/arm-none-eabi --with-libiconv-prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-gmp=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-mpfr=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-mpc=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-isl=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-cloog=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-libelf=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors' --with-multilib-list=armv6-m,armv7-m,armv7e-m,cortex-m7,armv7-r
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288] (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 
COMPILER_PATH=c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/armv6-m/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/;c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mcpu=cortex-m0plus' '-mthumb' '-mlittle-endian' '-Og' '-fmessage-length=0' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fno-common' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wmissing-declarations' '-Wshadow' '-g3' '-ggdb' '-T' 'C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template\Misc\stm32f0-discovery.ld' '-nostartfiles' '-LC:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\lib' '-specs=nano.specs' '-v' '-static' '-o' 'Template.elf'
 c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/collect2.exe -plugin c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\Lenny\AppData\Local\Temp\ccm3aIUJ.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lg_nano -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc_nano -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc_nano --sysroot=c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../arm-none-eabi -EL -Bstatic -X -o Template.elf -LC:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\lib -Lc:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/armv6-m -Lc:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m -Lc:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m -Lc:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3 -Lc:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib -Lc:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib --gc-sections -Map Template.map --cref --start-group -lc_nano -lgcc -lnosys --end-group ./Source/main.o -lopencm3_stm32f0 -lc_nano -lnosys --start-group -lgcc -lg_nano -lc_nano --end-group --start-group -lgcc -lc_nano --end-group -T C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template\Misc\stm32f0-discovery.ld
'Finished building target: Template.elf'
' '
make --no-print-directory post-build
'Call post_build.py'
python C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template\Misc\post_build.py "C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/stm32f0-libopencm3/Template" "Debug" "Template"
arm-none-eabi-objdump -S "C:\Users\Lenny\Documents\Eclipse\stm32f0-libopencm3\Template\Debug\Template.elf" > "C:\Users\Lenny\Documents\Eclipse\stm32f0-libopencm3\Template\Debug\Template.lst"
' '
'Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Create Flash Image'
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "Template.elf"  "Template.hex"
'Finished building: Template.hex'
' '
'Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size'
arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "Template.elf"
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    500       0       0     500     1f4 Template.elf
'Finished building: Template.siz'
' '

19:07:04 Build Finished (took 2s.662ms)
```

**stm32f1 - maple, not wortking:**

```
19:43:56 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Template ****
make all 
'Building file: ../Source/main.c'
'Invoking: Cross ARM C Compiler'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd -Og -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -msoft-float -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow  -g3 -ggdb -DSTM32F1 -I"C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include" -I"C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/maple-mini/Template/Include" -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls -Wa,-adhlns="Source/main.o.lst" -v -MMD -MP -MF"Source/main.d" -MT"Source/main.o" -c -o "Source/main.o" "../Source/main.c"
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/src/gcc/configure --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw --libexecdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/lib --infodir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info --mandir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/man --htmldir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/html --pdfdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/pdf --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-headers=yes --with-newlib --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-sysroot=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/arm-none-eabi --with-libiconv-prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-gmp=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-mpfr=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-mpc=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-isl=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-cloog=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-libelf=/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors' --with-multilib-list=armv6-m,armv7-m,armv7e-m,cortex-m7,armv7-r
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288] (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mcpu=cortex-m3' '-mthumb' '-mlittle-endian' '-mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd' '-Og' '-fmessage-length=0' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wmissing-declarations' '-Wshadow' '-g3' '-ggdb' '-D' 'STM32F1' '-I' 'C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include' '-I' 'C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/maple-mini/Template/Include' '-std=gnu11' '-Wmissing-prototypes' '-Wstrict-prototypes' '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' '-Wredundant-decls' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MF' 'Source/main.d' '-MT' 'Source/main.o' '-c' '-o' 'Source/main.o'
 c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -I C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include -I C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/maple-mini/Template/Include -imultilib armv7-m -iprefix c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/ -isysroot c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../arm-none-eabi -MMD Source/main.d -MF Source/main.d -MP -MT Source/main.o -dD -D__USES_INITFINI__ -D STM32F1 ../Source/main.c -quiet -dumpbase main.c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd -mfloat-abi=soft -auxbase-strip Source/main.o -g3 -ggdb -Og -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls -std=gnu11 -version -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -o C:\Users\Lenny\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd3YTdy.s
GNU C (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) version 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288] (arm-none-eabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.4, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../arm-none-eabi/home/build/work/GCC-4-9-build/install-mingw/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/arm-gnu-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../arm-none-eabi/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\ARM-GNU-Toolchain\libopencm3\include
 C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/Eclipse/maple-mini/Template/Include
 c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include
 c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include-fixed
 c:\arm-gnu-toolchain\gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2-20150609-win32\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include
End of search list.
GNU C (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) version 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288] (arm-none-eabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.4, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 9d74dec9c13b63cc54577fa808c91d66
../Source/main.c: In function 'gpio_setup':
../Source/main.c:38:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gpio_mode_setup' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  gpio_mode_setup(PORT_LED, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT, GPIO_PUPD_NONE, PIN_LED);
  ^
../Source/main.c:38:28: error: 'GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT' undeclared (first use in this function)
  gpio_mode_setup(PORT_LED, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT, GPIO_PUPD_NONE, PIN_LED);
                            ^
../Source/main.c:38:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../Source/main.c:38:46: error: 'GPIO_PUPD_NONE' undeclared (first use in this function)
  gpio_mode_setup(PORT_LED, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT, GPIO_PUPD_NONE, PIN_LED);
                                              ^
make: *** [Source/main.o] Fehler 1

19:43:57 Build Finished (took 567ms)
```

I am pretty sure its a stupid mistake, but I cant find it by my own and hope you can give me a hint.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure there is a gpio_mode_setup? As I look in libopencm3 for the f1 it's gpio_set_mode.

Comment: that was the problem! the minimalblink.c differ for the two architectures. havent thought of that. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libopencm3 library interfaces for the mentioned architectures are different.

For the f1 the function is gpio_set_mode and not gpio_mode_setup. Also the defines are slightly different.